# Nested Validations in angular 6?

Tags: regex, angular

I want to put a validation in angular 6. It should contain alpha numeric characters. Either Alphabets or Numeric, 3 to 9 digits only.
 It should start with 1 if it is Numeric.

Can anybody help me with these validation ?

```
Validators.pattern("[^[A-Z a-z | \d 1 ] ]")

Can anybody please help me in this?
```

Comment: Try `^(?:1\d{2,8}|[A-Za-z]{3,9})$` https://regex101.com/r/k8P4oF/1 Should the alphabets also be 3 - 9 characters?

Comment: create a function and set the flag using if-else loop and use the lag in place of validation

Comment: You can create custom validator with which you can check multiple regex or conditions.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48350506/how-to-validate-password-strength-with-angular-5-validator-pattern

Comment: @Thefourthbird yes, the alphabets should also be 3-9 chars, & if it starts with number it should only start with 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could match either 9 digits, starting with 1 and followed by 8 digits 0-9 or match a char a-zA-Z and repeat that 9 times using an [alternation](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html)

```
^(?:1\d{2,8}|[A-Za-z]{3,9})$
```

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of string
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `1\d{2,8}` Match 1 followed by 2-8 digits to match 3-9 times
  - `|` Or
  - `[A-Za-z]{3,9}` Match a char a-zA-Z and repeat that 3-9 times
- `)` Close group
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/k8P4oF/1)